# Use in AppNexus API

Tags: python, api, curl

I need to build a code that connects to AppNexus API, to create/update segments, and upload users lists.

I thought the easy way will be by Python, since I found this library: https://appnexus-client.readthedocs.io/en/feature-readthedocs/get_started.html

However, all the examples I find online are exactly the same as in the link - a very shallow use in one option that doesn't relates to the real abilities this tool has.

Does anyone knows if there's a good documentation out there for AppNexus?
Maybe someone already tried it and can recommend a nice and easier way to connect to their API (I saw in AppNexus documentation a large use in curl commands)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Postman or terminal to authenticate into AppNexus and then run the curl commands, AppNexus Segments Doc has samples on how to do this here: (https://wiki.appnexus.com/display/api/Segment+Service) You can also use a library to turn curl commands into your preferred programming language for example in Ruby you can use curl-to-ruby: (https://jhawthorn.github.io/curl-to-ruby/)